# How to remove duplicates in subarrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

It is not a duplicate! The link above doesn't show how to delete all other subarrays values by index of the third subarray (see expected array).

This code finds duplicates:

```js
    var array = [];
    
    array[0] = [0, "1:7001", "1:7002", "1:7003", "1:7004", "1:7005"];
    array[1] = [1, "1:8001", "1:8002", "1:8003", "1:8004", "1:8005"];
    array[2] = ["asw", 32884789084, 32919691801, 32919691801, 32919691801, 32857764298];
    
    var dup = array[2].filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) !== i);
    
    console.log(dup);
```

But I don't know how to delete elements in subarrays. Expected array should look like:

```
[0, "1:7001", "1:7002", "1:7005"]; 
[1, "1:8001", "1:8002", "1:8005"];
["asw", 32884789084, 32919691801, 32857764298];
```

Comment: i do not see ant duplicate in the array

Comment: @brk there are duplicates in the 3rd subarray. check properly.

Comment: You want to delete duplicate value from third array only, m i right?

Comment: @Chandan Kumar, no, I'd like to delete fram all arrays

Answer (score 2):

**You can do it like this with help of `map` and `Set`**

So with map here i am iterating each element of array variable. and than making a set out of each subarray (which means it will have only unique items). and before returning i am using spread operator to de-structure.

```js
var array = [];
    
    array[0] = [0, "1:7001", "1:7002", "1:7003", "1:7004", "1:7005"];
    array[1] = [1, "1:8001", "1:8002", "1:8003", "1:8004", "1:8005"];
    array[2] = ["asw", 32884789084, 32919691801, 32919691801, 32919691801, 32857764298];
    
    
    var dup = array.map(e=>[...new Set(e)])
    
    console.log(dup);
```

If you want to remove elements from other subarray based on 3rd subarray you can do it like this.

```js
var array = [];
     
array[0] = [0, "1:7001", "1:7002", "1:7003", "1:7004", "1:7005"];
array[1] = [1, "1:8001", "1:8002", "1:8003", "1:8004", "1:8005"];
array[2] = ["asw", 32884789084, 32919691801, 32919691801, 32919691801, 32857764298];
        
let op = array.map((e,ind,a)=>{
  return e.filter((el,i)=>{
    return  i == 0 ? true : a[2][i] !== a[2][i-1]
  })
})
        
        console.log(op);
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit how it works? By the way it's not removing elements from first and second subarrays.

Comment: @F.Vosnim check the updated one and i don't see any duplicates in the first and second one.

Comment: Delete all other subarrays values by index of the third subarray (see expected array)

Comment: ES6 Style :: const arr = ["asw", 32884789084, 32919691801, 32919691801, 32919691801, 32857764298];
    let s = new Set(arr)
    let it = s.values()
    console.log(Array.from(it))

Comment: @Chandan Kumar, thank you. But it's not helping to delete other subarrays values.

Comment: You can put this logic inside for long and change arr value

Comment: @F.Vosnim check the updated answer.

Comment: @Code Maniac, thank you very much! But it's keeping last element, not the first

Comment: @F.Vosnim oh yeah. now it is keeping :)

Comment: @Code Maniac, I found that if `array[2] = ["a","b","c","c","a","b","e"]` it removes only `c` and does not remove second `"a","b"`.